# Recreating a For Loop in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop, where-clause

I am trying to recreate a for loop in SQL. I have a table which has fields such as company ID, Company Name, Fiscal Year, Fiscal Quarter and various Data Items. For each Data Item ID, I need to grab the Data Item Value for all the companies and select the rows which have the greatest fiscal year and greatest fiscal quarter. For example, if this is my sample table:

```
Company ID | Fiscal Year | Fiscal Quarter | DataItemID | DataItem Value 
1          | 2018        | 1              | 100        | $200,000  
1          | 2018        | 3              | 100        | $250,000
1          | 2017        | 4              | 200        | 35.5 
2          | 2017        | 4              | 100        | $500,000 
2          | 2018        | 1              | 200        | 40.0
2          | 2016        | 2              | 100        | $400,000 
2          | 2017        | 3              | 200        | 50.5
```

My output should be:

```
Company ID | Fiscal Year | Fiscal Quarter | DataItemID | DataItem Value  
1          | 2018        | 3              | 100        | $250,000
1          | 2017        | 4              | 200        | 35.5 
2          | 2017        | 4              | 100        | $500,000 
2          | 2018        | 1              | 200        | 40.0
```

So for each dataitemID, loop through all companies and select the row with the greatest fiscalyear and fiscalquarter for each company along with the dataItem Value.

I have the below code that partially works. For one DataItemID it works perfectly. However for multiple dataitems, it's not looping through all the companies.

```
SELECT top (1) with ties companyid, COMPANYName, dataitemname, fiscalyear,fiscalquarter, periodtypeid, dataitemvalue As Data_Value

    FROM dbo.ciqCompany  
    -- List out dataitems to report  
  WHERE dataItemID IN (100,200)

    order by row_number() over (partition by companyId order by fiscalyear desc, fiscalquarter desc)
```

I think the issue is with the Where-Clause " WHERE dataItemID IN (100,200)". Since this is an "OR" condition, it does not pick up all the records for each ID. Any thoughts on this will be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: Why is the year 2016 not present in the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need `DataItemID` in `partition` clause

```
. . .
row_number() over (partition by companyId, DataItemID order by fiscalyear desc, fiscalquarter desc)
```

Comment: Thank you! Very weird that I din't think to do that! Thanks!

Comment: Correct and i thought i may have posted after you but i beat you this once by 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add an additional partition by to include `DataItemID`

```
 order by row_number() over (partition by companyId, DataItemID order by fiscalyear desc, fiscalquarter desc)
```

Comment: Thank you! Very weird that I din't think to do that! Thanks!

Comment: No worries at all @Amritha!